# Calculus Integration answer

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int{\frac{3}{5y^2 + 4}}dy$$

$$\frac{3}{4}\int{\frac{1}{\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}y}{2}\right)^2 + 1}}dy$$

$$u = \frac{\sqrt{5}y}{2}$$

$$dy = \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}du$$

My solution to this problem was

$$\frac{3}{2\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{1}{\tan\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}y}{2}\right)} + c\right)$$

However, apparently the solution is as follows:
$$\frac{3}{2\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{1}{\tan\frac{\sqrt{5}y}{2}}\right) + c $$

My question is: why is c outside the bracket? I was taught that when you integrate a value you must add c.  But since we're adding c, we also must multiply by whatever is outside of the integral.

Comment: It is just the same. Just expand your expression and you have another constant.

Comment: Did anybody notice that the integral is wrong?

Comment: Note: your answer is wrong. It should be $\frac{3}{2\sqrt{5}}\left(\tan^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{5}y}{2}\right) + c $, not $\frac{3}{2\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{1}{\tan\frac{\sqrt{5}y}{2}}\right) + c $. $tan^{-1}(x) \ne \frac{1}{\tan(x)}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that $c$ is a generic constant - it doesn't hold a particular value until it is assigned one. In this case, note that $\frac{3}{2\sqrt{5}}*c$ is still a constant. 
$$\frac{3}{2\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{1}{\tan(\frac{\sqrt{5}y}{2})} + c\right)=\frac{3}{2\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{1}{\tan(\frac{\sqrt{5}y}{2})}\right)+\frac{3}{2\sqrt{5}}*c$$
$$\frac{3}{2\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{1}{\tan(\frac{\sqrt{5}y}{2})}\right)+c$$

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't matter if c is inside or outside the bracket. It just denotes a constant value.
If you multiply the coefficient with the constant, you will just get another constant.

Answer (score 1):

This is because what ever the value is that is being multiplied is still a constant. The mathematician does not concern themselves with any magnitude of this constant when solving empirically.